# when I try python3 version it does not work as a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have the following docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python3 \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pip
USER root
COPY scripts scripts
RUN ls
RUN pwd
RUN chmod +x ./scripts/functional_test_cli/baft.py
COPY tests tests
RUN pip3 install Pytest
RUN pip3 install pytest-json-report
RUN pip3 install Tavern
RUN pip3 install allure-pytest
RUN pip3 install pytest-pythonpath
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN which python

RUN python3 version
CMD ["python3", "./scripts/functional_test_cli/baft.py"]
```

So when it comes to this line  RUN python3 version it throw the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Am I missing anything? why python3 is not recognized as a command?

Comment: Note: you should use a requirements file (or Pipenv), not individual pip commands. You could also start from an existing python image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about change to `python3 --version` or `python3 -V`

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3

$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
```

I think there are no command just `version` on python.

(It may look like file reference. Thanks to @cricket_007)

```sh
$ python3 version
python3: can't open file 'version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's not a command, it is seen as a file reference

Comment: Yeap, thank for your supplement!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check which version of python is installed it should be `python3 --version`. If you execute it without the dashes it means you want to run a script named "version".

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether your python3 installed or not with

```
python3 --version
```

or

```
python3 -V
```

but this error is because of your docker demon not able to find your *bafi.py* file